# How to remove object from core-data in swift

Tags: swift, core-data

I'm learning swift and I have a problem when I'm trying to delete an object from `CoreData`

My application have two pages, one page is search (to search recipes) and the other is the favorite page (where I put my favorite recipes)

When I go to the detail of a recipe in my search page I'm able to add and remove a recipe to/from favorite (everything works) but when I wan't to remove the favorite from the favorite page, my application crash with "found nil while unwrapping optional"

```
var storage = RecipeStorageManager()

var recipeDetail: Hit!

var recipe: RecipeToSave

var isFavorite: Bool {
    return storage.fetchAll().contains(where: { $0.url == self.recipeDetail.recipe.url })
}

let request: NSFetchRequest<RecipeToSave> = RecipeToSave.fetchRequest()



@objc func favTapped(_ sender: Any!) {
    if isFavorite == true {
        print("favvv")
        removeFromFav()
    } else {
        addToFav()
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = .green
    }
}


func addToFav() {
    recipe = storage.insertRecipe(label: recipeDetail.recipe.label,
                             url: recipeDetail.recipe.url,
                             image: recipeDetail.recipe.image,
                             ingredientLines: recipeDirections.text,
                             totalTime: recipeDetail.recipe.totalTime)
    print("added fav")

    storage.save()
}


func removeFromFav() {
    storage.remove(recipeID: recipe.objectID)
    print("removed")
    storage.save()
    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Hi @Nasch. Which line do you get a crash?

Comment: storage.remove(recipeID: recipe.objectID) at this line

Comment: Can you check `recipe` on console? Write `po recipe` in console when you get crash. I think it is `nil`. You can create recipe  of optional variable  `var recipe: RecipeToSave?` and call remove function `storage.remove(recipeID: recipe?.objectID)`. This is solve the crash but you should solve the recipe object's nil value.

Answer (score 0):

You are saying

```
var recipeDetail: Hit!
var isFavorite: Bool {
    return storage.fetchAll().contains(where: { $0.url == self.recipeDetail.recipe.url })
}
```

So any time you say `recipeDetail` or `isFavorite` in your code, if `recipeDetail` is `nil`, you crash.

Comment: Only if i'm in the favorite page but it's the same controller for the 2 page

Comment: You have not given any relevant information other than this tiny snippet of code. Your question was that you are crashing with a nil optional. I have explained correctly based on the code you showed why that is happening. If you want to know _why_ `recipeDetail` is `nil` you would need to show more code and ask a question about that.

Comment: i don't know what i can show you to explain better so you, if you wan't you can see the full project on my github: https://github.com/MrNasch/Reciplease

Comment: Excellent but I'm not going to search through all your code guessing under what circumstances the crash happens. You need to explain what you're doing when it occurs. Do you realize that you have not even said what class the problematic code is in? Please make an effort to ask your question better.